# How to vary the amount of a bump mapping effect on an object?

Tags: texturing, displacement

How do I vary the amount of a bump mapping effect on an object in cycles? I wanted to make a planet with a volcano using the both displacement method, but the effect displaced my volcano more than I wanted, as you can see.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add a math node before the displacement, set it to multiply and by changing the values you can control how pronounced the displacement will be.

Comment: I did that and also added a mapping node and that solved it.